# Can't access annotation of field in Java

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

I have annotation

```
public @interface Equals {
String name() default "unknown";
}
```

and class whose field is annotated by Equals

```
public class TransportSearch {
@Equals(name="vin")
public String vin = null;
}
```

and I have one method in another class

```
public String (TransportSearch transportSearch){
    Field[] fields = transportSearch.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

    String vin = null;

    for(Field field : fields){
        try {
            Equals annot = field.getAnnotation(Equals.class);

            if(annot!=null && annot.name().equals("vin")){
                try {
                    vin = (String) field.get(transportSearch);
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        } catch(NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return vin;
}
```

unfortunately in this method `field.getAnnotation(Equals.class)` returns null and I can't understand why?
Can you help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must set the [RetentionPolicy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html) of your annotation to `RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME`:

```
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Equals {
    String name() default "unknown";
}
```

The default `RetentionPolicy` is `RetentionPolicy.CLASS`, which means the annotation does not need to be available at runtime.

Comment: Little correction: The default RetentoinPolicy is RetentionPolicy.CLASS. But it is nevertheless a correct answer.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Thanks for the correction - I edited my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score -1):

If you use kotlin：

```
class TransportSearch {
  @field:Equals(name = "vin")
  var vin:String? = null
}
```